# HA Postgresql in K8s - Different data when querying SVC or Pods

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, bitnami

I am getting crazy about this. I have a ha-postgresql bitanmi chart deployed in mi k8s cluster using ClusterIP.

But when I query the SVC endpoint I get different information from the one I get when I query any of the three Pods running the database.

Why do i have this data difference? How do I Avoid it?

I checked and the SVC is pointing towards each pod endpoint.

When I connect against the SVC:

```
k port-forward svc/backend-main-postgresql-ha-postgresql 5432:5432
```

I get only one record in the DB:

```
my_db=# select * from status;

id                  |    element_id    | element_type | request_no  |    status    | requester
--------------------------------------+------------------+--------------+-------------+--------------+-----------
5034e58b-8a6d-4ed5-a754-1dd47b5a1a23 | TESTELEMENTNAME5 | TypeA| RRRR4506288 | PROVISIONING | REQUESTER1
```

But when I query any of the three pods:

```
k port-forward backend-main-postgresql-ha-postgresql-0 5433:5432 -n api-exchange-test
```

It shows me the different data that has been inserted into the database.

```
my_db=# select * from status;

id                  |    element_id    | element_type | request_no  |    status    | requester
 --------------------------------------+------------------+--------------+-------------+--------------+-----------
715898b1-e196-4a95-a846-9d962c3e2fa6 | TESTELEMENTNAME5 | TypeA        | RRRR4506248  | PROVISIONING | DD2D3D2
fce779f4-bf55-48fc-b7ec-ca16c806b147 | TESTELEMENTNAME5 | TypeA        | RRRR4506249  | PROVISIONING | AD22342
2e73d74e-803b-4c19-ac08-6a2f5d570308 | RRRRRRNPRUEBA     | TypeA        | RRRR87654321 | PROVISIONED  | ABC2222
e6eea448-f9d8-464f-a317-6b199643b631 | TESTELEMENTNAME5 | TypeA        | RRRR4506257  | PROVISIONING | ABC2222
904353ce-d532-44ae-8bff-22a817bdfc39 | TTTTTT787488768  | RRRRR        | RRRR4506387  | PROVISIONING | AD17028
e6065436-809d-47c0-b41e-0d4053ed0852 | PPPG31787701681  | PPPPP        | RRRR4506388  | PROVISIONING | ABC2222
3b9d8388-60c9-4854-8cf8-cc80c98eaa27 | YYYYYY787489664  | TypeA        | RRRR4506390  | PROVISIONING | ABC2222
```

It has three replicas and SVC seems to point to the pods properly:

```
:~$ k describe svc -n api-exchange-test api-hub-backend-main-postgresql-ha-postgresql
Name:              backend-main-postgresql-ha-postgresql
Namespace:         test
Labels:            app.kubernetes.io/component=postgresql
app.kubernetes.io/instance=backend-main
app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm
app.kubernetes.io/name=postgresql-ha
helm.sh/chart=postgresql-ha-11.7.5
Annotations:       meta.helm.sh/release-name: api-hub-backend-main                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      meta.helm.sh/release-namespace:test
Selector:          app.kubernetes.io/component=postgresql,app.kubernetes.io/instance=backend-main,app.kubernetes.io/name=postgresql-ha,role=data
Type:              ClusterIP
IP Families:       <none>
IP:                10.96.125.28
IPs:               <none>
Port:              postgresql  5432/TCP
TargetPort:        postgresql/TCP
Endpoints:         148.155.197.134:5432,148.155.211.68:5432,148.155.219.187:5432
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
```

The pods:

```
:~$ k get pods - -o wide
NAME                                                              READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE    IP                NODE                        NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
main-springboot-ms-68bf469678-l5l96         1/1     Running   0          2d8h   148.155.193.4     
dcomx73y-b3.corp.intranet   <none>           <none>
backend-main-postgresql-ha-pgpool-5555bcdf6d-4rncw        1/1     Running   0          27m    148.155.213.2     dcomx375-b1.corp.intranet   <none>           <none>
backend-main-postgresql-ha-postgresql-0                   1/1     Running   0          30m    148.155.197.134   dcomx69y-b3.corp.intranet   <none>           <none>
backend-main-postgresql-ha-postgresql-1                   1/1     Running   0          31m    148.155.219.187   dcomx372-b3.corp.intranet   <none>           <none>                                                                                                                          backend-main-postgresql-ha-postgresql-2                   1/1     Running   0          31m    148.155.211.68    dcomx68y-b3.corp.intranet   <none>           <none>
```

This is my values.yaml content, so most values are defaults:

```
    postgresql-ha:
      global:
        postgresql:
          database: dbName
          extraVolumeMounts:
          - mountPath: /dev/shm
            name: dshm
          extraVolumes:
          - emptyDir:
              medium: Memory
              sizeLimit: 512Mi
            name: dshm
          password: mypassword
          postgresPassword: mypassword
          repmgrPassword: mypassword
          repmgrUsername: postgresUser
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: 500m
              memory: 500Mi
          username: postgresUser
        storageClass: test-sc
      persistence:
        enabled: true
        storageClass: test-sc
      pgpool:
        adminPassword: mypassword
      postgresql:
        password: mypassword
        postgresPassword: mypassword
        repmgrPassword: mypassword
        repmgrUsername: postgresUser
        username: postgresUser
```

Comment: I have been checking and the issue seems to be in the replication, either connecting with the pgpool or the svc, there are different replication data.

The * pg_stat_replication* tables shows no columns, I provided no replication value in my helm-values.yaml assuming it will do the replication by itself